# Sort a part of a list in place

Tags: python, sorting, in-place

Let's say we have a list:

```
a = [4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 0, 5, 2, 6, 9]
```

Now, a.sort() will sort the list in place. What if we want to sort only *a part* of the list, still in place? In C++ we could write:

```
int array = { 4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 0, 5, 2, 6, 9 };
int * ptr = array;
std::sort( ptr + 1, ptr + 4 );
```

Is there a similar way in Python?

Comment: Why the need to only sort in-place?

Comment: I think that this would be a good thing to request to be added to Python. It would just be optional arguments of start and end to the standard sort() method.

Comment: A good reason for in-place sort is a case where you want to sort the end of the list (that is already mostly sorted, perhaps by a less-expensive key function), and then pop the last value. Ran into this use case when constructing a mostly-greedy TSP solution. Will likely go with the solution by @fviktor.

Answer (score 93):

I'd write it this way:

```
a[i:j] = sorted(a[i:j])
```

It is not in-place sort either, but fast enough for relatively small segments.

Please note, that Python copies only object references, so the speed penalty won't be that huge compared to a real in-place sort as one would expect.

Comment: The OP actually asked for integers. For an array of integer, copying references is not supposed to be significantly faster than copying the actual values.

Comment: The question does not state that the list can only contain integers. The C++ example indeed operates on integers, but that does not mean that the question is limited only to that.

Comment: I don't think this is as good as using quicksort, because it requires O(N) extra memory, whereas quicksort uses O(1) extra memory.  I left an answer down below with a quicksort implementation

Comment: It's not an in-place sort.

Answer (score 41):

if `a` is a `numpy` array then to sort `[i, j)` range in-place, type:

```
a[i:j].sort()
```

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 0, 5, 2, 6, 9])
>>> a[1:4].sort()
>>> a
array([4, 1, 7, 8, 3, 0, 5, 2, 6, 9])
```

Comment: We do not want to use numpy

Comment: It works for usual list (not numpy array) as well (at least in Python 3.10)

Comment: @YuriiMotov it doesn't: https://replit.com/@zed1/InplaceSliceSort#main.py

Answer (score 3):

To sort between two indices in place, I would recommend using quicksort.  the advantage of quicksort over `array[start:end] = sorted(arr[start:end])` is that quicksort does not require any extra memory, whereas assigning to a slice requires O(n) extra memory.

I don't believe there is an implementation in the standard library, but it is easy to write yourself.  Here is an implementation that I copied and pasted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quicksort-using-random-pivoting/

```
import random 

def quicksort(arr, start , stop): 
    if(start < stop): 
        pivotindex = partitionrand(arr, start, stop) 
        quicksort(arr , start , pivotindex - 1) 
        quicksort(arr, pivotindex + 1, stop) 


def partitionrand(arr , start, stop): 

    randpivot = random.randrange(start, stop) 

    arr[start], arr[randpivot] = arr[randpivot], arr[start] 
    return partition(arr, start, stop) 


def partition(arr,start,stop): 
    pivot = start # pivot 
    i = start + 1 # a variable to memorize where the  
                  # partition in the array starts from. 
    for j in range(start + 1, stop + 1): 
        if arr[j] <= arr[pivot]: 
            arr[i] , arr[j] = arr[j] , arr[i] 
            i = i + 1
    arr[pivot] , arr[i - 1] = arr[i - 1] , arr[pivot] 
    pivot = i - 1
    return (pivot)
```

To sort between, say, indices 2 and 6 in your example (inclusive range), I would do something like this:

```
array = [4, 8, 1, 7, 3, 0, 5, 2, 6, 9]
quicksort(array, 2, 6) 
print(array)
```

Comment: copying and calling built-n `sort` implemented in C is almost always better than inplace sorting implemented in Python though