# Sort nested list: Exclude first item from sorting

Tags: python, list, csv, sorting

## SET

I have a `csv file` which includes the current balance of my refreshments (it is comma separated, but in this example commas `,` are removed for improved readability):

```
NAME         AMOUNT         PRICE
Coca-Cola    8              1.25
Fanta        6              1.29
Dr. Pepper   2              2.20
Sprite       10             1.35
Guarana      6              1.80
Pepsi        4              1.25
```

I read all the data into the memory (list) and do all the necessary editing using:

```
import csv
# format list for refreshments
items_list = []

with open("my_refresments.csv", newline='') as fileOpener:
    open_csv = csv.reader(fileOpener)
    for rows in open_csv:
        items_list.append(rows)
```

The list 'items_list' now prints out as:

```
items_list = [["NAME","AMOUNT","PRICE"],
              ["Coca-Cola","8","1.25"],
              ["Fanta","6","1.29"],
              ["Dr. Pepper","2","2.20"],
              ["Sprite","10","1.35"],
              ["Guarana","6","1.80"],
              ["Pepsi","4","1.25"]]
```

## QUESTION

What gives me this kind of sorting:

```
# Notice that this is sorted, but items_list[0] is at it's place

items_list = [["NAME","AMOUNT","PRICE"],
              ["Coca-Cola","8","1.25"],
              ["Fanta","6","1.29"],
              ["Dr. Pepper","2","2.20"],
              ["Sprite","10","1.35"],
              ["Guarana","6","1.80"],
              ["pepsi","4","1.25"]]
```

Everything except first row `items_list[0]` should stay unsorted ergo untouched where it stands.

### Sorting the list

Generally `a.sort()` is a good option with nested lists because it will not sort all the individual items inside the lists, but instead it sorts the lists compared one to another. In this case I can't use `items_list.sort()`, because it will include also the headers in csv file, which I want to stay just where it is already located: `items_list[0]`. Here is what happens when using `items_list.sort()`:

```
items_list.sort()
[['Coca-Cola', '8', '1.25'],
 ['Fanta', '6', '1.29'], 
 ['Dr. Pepper', '2', '2.20'], 
 ['Sprite', '10', '1.35'], 
 ['Guarana', '6', '1.80'], 
 ['NAME', 'AMOUNT', 'PRICE'], 
 ['Pepsi', '4', '1.25']]
```

Strangely, if I write all the refreshments with `lower case`, it will work, because `TEXT > text`, but **I don't want to do that**. I would like to use `slice` to exclude the first row (headers), but it doesn't seem to have any effect what so ever (or maybe I'm doing it wrong):

```
# This doesn't do anything
items_list[1:].sort()
```

### One possible solution

What I could do is to

1. first copy headers into another list in one way or another `temp_list = [items_list[0]]`
2. delete `items_list[0]` using the `del items_list[0]` statement
3. sort the list using `items_list.sort()`, and finally
4. insert headers into the sorted list's `index(0)` with `items_list.insert(0, temp_list)`

like this:

```
def sort_csv_list_exclude_headers(file_name):

    items_list = []

    with open(file_name, newline='') as fileOpener:
        open_csv = csv.reader(fileOpener)
        for rows in open_csv:
            items_list.append(rows)

    temp_list = [items_list[0]]
    del items_list[0]
    items_list.sort()
    items_list.insert(0, temp_list[0])

    with open(file_name, "w") as fileWriter:
        write_csv = csv.writer(fileWriter, lineterminator='\n')
        write_csv.writerows(items_list)

sort_csv_list_exclude_headers("SODA_BALANCE.csv")
```

Actually this is pretty good and simple in general when using csv with > 1 000 000 rows of "refreshments".

### Subquestion

Is there any other (more simple) method?

Comment: the `.sort` method works in place, so doing `items_list[1:].sort()` creates a new list, `items_list[1:]`, then you sort that new list, but the method returns `None`, and you never capture the result and thus the list is immediately discarded. Use `sorted`, which *returns a new list*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A clean one liner will be:

```
items_list[1:] = sorted(items_list[1:])
```

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5827649/937153

Answer (score 0):

It is simple possible solution,

```
[items_list[0]] + sorted(items_list[1:])
```

or Use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) If there's no reason not to use

[pandas sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141558/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-by-two-or-more-columns)

---

thanks to juanpa.arrivillaga

To explain why use `sorted()` not `.sort()`

`sorted()` return sorted list, but `.sort()` is change list it self. (not return)

so If you want to use `.sort()` then code will be

```
values = items_list[1:].sort()
item_list = [item_list[0]] + values
```

using `sorted` is more short!

Comment: You should explain *why* `.sort` doesn't work

Comment: `.sort` is work well, but `sorted()` return sorted list, but `.sort` doesn't

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think this is good comment!

Comment: yes, add your explanation to the question by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46398224/edit)

Comment: What are the advatages of `pandas` in my application?

Comment: Pandas offers many different features, and its very fast.
when I handle large csv files or many columns, values, `pandas` is faster than just `csv`

Comment: @Maybe: Switching to pandas just to get this working is an absolute overkill. In general they are useful for handling large amount of data.

Comment: It may be, cuz I do not know the whole program

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to use `pandas`.

Read the csv using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_refresments.csv")
df.sort_values("PRICE")
```

which sorts the data according to price, and the header is stored in `df.columns`, so it is not sorted with the actual data.