# list sort not working on part of a list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort part of a list.

My list is

`A=[3,2,8,1,0,5,4,6,7,9]`

I am able to sort the entire list by A.sort()

```
A.sort() -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

When I apply sort() on part of the list, it doesn't work as expected. My list remains the same.

```
A[0:4].sort()-> [3,2,8,1,0,5,4,6,7,9]
```

I know sorted() will work as expected when I apply on part of a list but I would like to know why sort() does't work on part of the list.

Comment: Slicing creates a new list which is getting sorted; but your original list is untouched.

Comment: try `A[0:4] = A[0:4].sort()`

Comment: damn, there's always a duplicate :)

Comment: If slicing a list create a new list which gets sorted out, isn't the same applicable to a numpy array? . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272819/sort-a-part-of-a-list-in-place . This question has an answer in which they are sorting part of a numpy array using sort.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
A=[3,2,8,1,0,5,4,6,7,9]
A[0:4] = sorted(A[0:4])
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 8, 0, 5, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```