# Sort a list from an index to another index

Tags: python, list, sorting

Suppose I have a list `[2, 4, 1, 3, 5]`.

I want to sort the list just from index 1 to the end, which gives me `[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]`

How can I do it in Python?

(No extra spaces would be appreciated)

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you want this?

Comment: I'm trying to make a next_permutation() in python

Comment: Do you really need to *sort* for that, though? Not just *reverse*?

Comment: Yup, reverse is ok, but I just curious to ask about sorting this way.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2272819/12671057

Comment: Very good suggestions. Coming from a C++ background, I just want to understand more about memory cost in python

Comment: @nwice13: How is your `next_permutation()` supposed to work, then? E.g. with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## TL;DR:

Use `sorted` with a slicing assignment to keep the original list object without creating a new one:

```
l = [2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
l[1:] = sorted(l[1:])
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

## Longer Answer:

After the list is created, we will make a slicing assignment:

```
l[1:] =
```

Now you might be wondering what does `[1:]`, it is slicing the list and starts from the second index, so the first index will be dropped. Python's indexing starts from zero, `:` means get everything after the index before, but if it was `[1:3]` it will only get values that are in between the indexes `1` and `3`, let's say your list is:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you use:

```
print(l[1:])
```

It will result in:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And if you use:

```
print(l[1:3])
```

It will result in:

```
[2, 3]
```

About slicing, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) if you want to.

And after slicing we have an equal sign `=`, that just simply changes what's before the `=` sign to what's after the `=` sign, so in this case, we use `l[1:]`, and that gives `[2, 3, 4, 5]`, it will change that to whatever is after the `=` sign.

If you use:

```
l[1:] = [100, 200, 300, 400]
print(l)
```

It will result in:

```
[1, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```

To learn more about it check out [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

After that, we got `sorted`, which is default builtin function, it simple sorts the list from small to big, let's say we have the below list:

```
l = [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

If you use:

```
print(sorted(l))
```

It will result in:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To learn more about it check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted).

After that we come back to our first topic about slicing, with `l[1:]`, but from here you know that it isn't only used for assignments, you can apply functions to it and deal with it, like here we use `sorted`.

Comment: That's good, also similar to another answer below, but also require some extra memory

Comment: @nwice13 It is sorting in place, that's what you want, i think this is your best bet

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica seconded. For the inplace operation, this is _the_ answer.

Comment: @nwice13 You are confusing two things, slicing and slice-based assignment. The expression `x[:]` creates a slice, implicitly calling `x.__getitem__`, whereas the statement `x[:] = b` is slice assignment, which calls `x.__setitem__`

Comment: If I didn't get wrong, the expression x[:] would just create a slice object but not the entire new list?

Comment: @nwice13 Take a look to understand better about slice=ing as assignment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623302/how-assignment-works-with-python-list-slice

Answer (score 12):

Maybe temporarily put something there that's smaller than the rest? Should be faster than the other solutions. And gets as close to your *"No extra spaces"* wish as you can get when using `sort` or `sorted`.

```
>>> tmp = l[0]
>>> l[0] = float('-inf')
>>> l.sort()
>>> l[0] = tmp
>>> l
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Benchmarks**

For the example list, 1,000,000 iterations (and mine of course preparing that special value only once):

```
  sort_u10 0.8149 seconds
sort_chris 0.8569 seconds
 sort_heap 0.7550 seconds
sort_heap2 0.5982 seconds   # using -1 instead of -inf
```

For 50,000 lists like `[int(x) for x in os.urandom(100)]`:

```
  sort_u10 0.4778 seconds
sort_chris 0.4786 seconds
 sort_heap 0.8106 seconds
sort_heap2 0.4437 seconds   # using -1 instead of -inf
```

Benchmark code:

```
import timeit, os

def sort_u10(l):
    l[1:] = sorted(l[1:])

def sort_chris(l):
    l = l[:1] + sorted(l[1:])

def sort_heap(l, smallest=float('-inf')):
    tmp = l[0]
    l[0] = smallest
    l.sort()
    l[0] = tmp

def sort_heap2(l):
    tmp = l[0]
    l[0] = -1
    l.sort()
    l[0] = tmp

for _ in range(3):
    for sort in sort_u10, sort_chris, sort_heap, sort_heap2, sort_rev:
        number, repeat = 1_000_000, 5
        data = iter([[2, 4, 1, 3, 5] for _ in range(number * repeat)])
        # number, repeat = 50_000, 5
        # data = iter([[int(x) for x in os.urandom(100)] for _ in range(number * repeat)])
        t = timeit.repeat(lambda: sort(next(data)), number=number, repeat=repeat)
        print('%10s %.4f seconds' % (sort.__name__, min(t)))
    print()
```

Comment: A bit cheating, but very good thought!

Comment: Whenever you see "Should be faster" but no benchmarks...  I'd expect it to be slightly (probably non-detecably) slower, as it requires an extra iteration to sort the extra value, compared to the slicing method.

Comment: @Baldrickk but you don't have the extra list creation / memory usage. I would also expect this solution to be faster. It at least beats the other solution when it comes to space complexity.

Comment: @GlennDJ Yeah, that's what I thought as well. Added benchmarks now.

Comment: Nice benchmarks, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Use `sorted` with slicing:

```
l[:1] + sorted(l[1:])
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: That is good. However, as far as I know, sorted and slicing would give me a completely new list. What I really want is sorting in place

Comment: Something that is similar to C++ STL: sort(a[i].begin() + 1, a.end())

Comment: If you need to sort with O(1) auxiliary space, you are going to have to implement a sorting algorithm yourself (or use one from a third-party library). Even the "in-place" `list.sort` method uses O(n) auxiliary space; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759175/what-is-the-space-complexity-of-the-python-sort/48759241

Answer (score 3):

For the special case that you actually have, according to our comments:

> Q: I'm curious: Why do you want this? – Heap Overflow
>   A: I'm trying to make a next_permutation() in python – nwice13
>   Q: Do you really need to *sort* for that, though? Not just *reverse*? – Heap Overflow
>   A: Yup, reverse is ok, but I just curious to ask about sorting this way. – nwice13

I'd do that like this:

```
l[1:] = l[:0:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own function in `python` using [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) and [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) and this function (your custom function) should take start and end index of the list.

Since list is mutable in python, I have written the function in such a way it doesn't modify the list passed. Feel free to modify the function. You can modify the list passed to this function to save memory if required.

```
def sortedList(li, start=0, end=None):
        if end is None:
                end = len(li)
        fi = []
        fi[:start] = li[:start]
        fi[start:end] = sorted(li[start:end])
        return fi


li = [2, 1, 4, 3, 0]
print(li)
print(sortedList(li, 1))
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 4, 3, 0]
[2, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```